# JPanel.removeAll() not functioning properly

Tags: java, swing, label, jpanel, removeall

So I'm currently teaching myself to use GUI, and I decided to go back to the code for a game of Go Fish that I created and add in a GUI to it. For the panel that holds the CPU Player's cards, it displays the back of some playing cards to indicate the size of the CPU's hand.

Whenever a change occurs in the CPU's hand size, my method `updateComputerCards` gets called to adjust the amount of cards appearing on the screen. It does this by calling the `removeAll()` method for my panel, and then proceeds to re-add the proper amount of card images.

My issue though, is that when the game first begins, and matches are found within the CPU's hand, the method works as intended, and the amount of cards appearing shrinks. However, every subsequent time that the method is called, nothing changes in the GUI despite the CPU having a hand of cards of a different size.

Through the debugger I can see that the `removeAll()` method is not removing all the components on the panel for some reason, even though it succeeds in doing so without issue the first time it is called. Can anyone help me out here?

```
    public void updateComputerCards(ArrayList<Integer> hand) {
        labelPanel.removeAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++) {
            labelPanel.add(computerCardLabels.get(i));
            labelPanel.add(b.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Call `labelPanel.revalidate()` and `labelPane.repaint()` at the end of the `updateComputerCards` method to trigger a layout and paint pass - Swing layouts are lazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the [repaint()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint--) method after making the changes.
See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much! Definitely will be giving that a read.

Comment: You may find that you need to use `revalidate` first, as this will trigger a layout pass - Swing layouts are lazy

Comment: I went ahead and added revalidate(). I'm sorry I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to GUI. What exactly is a layout pass?